# Insert row causing 404

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, handlebars.js

I've verified that my database and table are set up properly, and I'm trying to insert an element into my 'workouts' table.

**I use the following URL:**

```
http://52.39.3.148:3000/insertWorkout?name=Tom&weight=166&date=12%2F12%2F12&lbs=123&reps=12
```

**The insertWorkout handler:**

```
app.post('/insertWorkout',function(req,res,next){
    var context = {};
    pool.query("INSERT INTO workouts (`name`,`weight`,`date`,`lbs`,`reps`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", [req.body.name, req.body.weight, req.body.date, req.body.lbs, req.body.reps], function(err, result){
    if(err){
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
    res.render('home',context);
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the url in a browser? if so, this is an http GET request and your code is creating a POST request.

The issue is - when you're calling this request - all the parameters you send(name, weight, date, lbs, reps) are sent in 'req.query' and not in 'req.body' which causes all your values to be undefined.

If you want to keep it as a post request, you should call this API as a post, I suggest using a tool such as [dhc](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) to do so.

If you want to turn it into a GET request - use the following:

```
app.get('/insertWorkout',function(req,res,next){
    var context = {};
    pool.query("INSERT INTO workouts (`name`,`weight`,`date`,`lbs`,`reps`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", [req.query.name, req.query.weight, req.query.date, req.query.lbs, req.query.reps], function(err, result){
    if(err){
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    context.results = "Inserted id " + result.insertId;
    res.render('home',context);
  });
});
```